# Why AngularJS service can return only objects, when factory can return both primitives and objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

Factory can return both primitives and objects. Then what would be the reason to use service to return objects (type-friendly injection)?

```
// factory
app.factory('factoryService',function(){
  var returnObj = function() {
  };

  return new returnObj(); 
})

// service
app.service('service',function(){
  return this;
});
```

Comment: What you will (or already did!) notice is that `factory` is actually nearly-universal and can easily do the very same thing as `constant`, `service`, ... do.

Comment: @bardzusny it can be a substitute for value and service, but not for constant. Constants are available in the config phase. Services created by factory are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is commodity. If you have a constructor function, you can pass it to `service()` rather than having to create a factory that calls the constructor function and returns the created object.

BTW, `factory()` is another commodity that avoids creating a provider with a `$get()` function returning the service. It just makes the code shorter.